# Websphere 6.1 jar needed for WebService annotation

Tags: web-services, ejb-3.0, websphere

I'm using WebSphere 6.1 with the EBJ3 Feature Pack installed. Does anyone know what jar I need to include in my project from the AppServer folder of my WebSphere installation in order to be able to use the @WebService annoation? I cannot seem to find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will require either:

- The webservice Feature Pack for Websphere 6.1 http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg21264563
- A JAXWS implementation, such the Reference Implementation http://jax-ws.java.net/

Pay attention to the order of installation of the Websphere Feature Packs

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood my question. I already have the feature pack installed. My question is which specific jar do I need to include in my project to get the @WebService annotation?

Comment: @dcp EBJ3 Feature Pack brings you EJB3 Session Beans and JPA Entities, but Bean publication of WebServices requires the Webservice feature pack that is a different feature pack.

Comment: actually I still cannot find the jar. I tried with 7.0 and was able to find it, but then I had to downgrade back to 6.1 because client won't allow 7.0. So I don't know what jar this annotation is in. Do you know the exact jar?

Comment: @dcp To be more clear, you don't have any jar to include in your project when using the feature pack. The Webservice annotation is provided at runtime by the application server in the classpath if using the Webservice Feature Pack for websphere (not required in 7.0). Without the Webservice Feature Pack (that delivers you the Webservice annotation in the com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_6.1.0.jar) you have to use a third party library (jar), such JAXWS-RI but not the one of WAS.
Feel free to ask for details if it is not clear.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the info I needed!

Answer (score 0):

WAS_HOME/lib/j2ee.jar

Note that in WAS 7.0+, all JARs needed for development are located in WAS_HOME/dev/.

Comment: I checked that jar, but there is no javax.jws.WebService class present. I'm using 6.1, not 7.0.

Comment: Sorry.  As snowflake says, you need the webservices feature pack to get webservices annotations, then my answer should be correct.

Comment: Thanks, but the answer is still not correct, it's not in j2ee.jar.

Answer (score 0):

WAS_HOME/plugins/ - com.ibm.jaxws.tools_6.1.0.jar
You may also need to include com.ibm.jaxb.tools, com.ibm.ws.runtime and org.apache.axis2 jars too.